# Do animal names correspond with verbs that have to do with their use to humans or their observed behaviour?

Tags: etymology

In an earlier question here I used an example of animal names versus words (often verbs) that have rather similar spelling and can be linked by observations of behaviour or the functional use to humans.
The reactions to the example differed from nonsense to coincidence, while I see a clear pattern with a logical explanation.

So again some examples:
A hound hunts
A dog digs
A sheep is shaven (for its wool) compare German Schaff)
A cat catches (rodents)
A cow chews (grass a lot with 4 stomachs...)
A fly... flies
A rabbit is rapid
A squirrel secures (this relates to the hiding of food in the ground for the winter.)
A sparrow (passerine bird) which appears and passes on forraging for food; French ‘il se apparu’ meaning ‘he appeared’
A wasp (French il va se poignez (Va-se-p...) meaning ‘he is going to be poignant (sharp/fierce))
An otter in the water
A beetle: voir cette bête aller
An owl flies at night: vole (la nuit)
A worm morrows (anagrammic antonym)
A bug (bukken means ‘to bend’ in Dutch. The name seems to indicate bending to the earth to see what kind of bug it is.

When does nonsense or coincidence become a pattern in linguistics?

Comment: How about snake:sneak?  You can also try it with plants.  Some work, some may share deep roots (cow:chew), but most ignore etymological research.

Comment: Yes, I think so too, that they share roots that express the same idea (not meaning). If you are investigating the idea and not the meaning you have to ignore the etymology research but up to the point that there is not just room for a one on one translation but a relation in (and here are a lot of options); what does the animal do, what sound does it make, what use has it to humans, what would people do to identify it, what would people do to warn others out of earlier experiences with the animal. And one can think of many more.

Comment: You should not ignore etymology.  For instance, 'rabbit' might mean *little thief*, and 'rapid' meant *take by force*.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question: "when does coincidence become a pattern?" is a perfectly relevant linguistic question, and one that e.g. Proto-World enthusiasts would do well to ask.

Comment: Me too.........

Comment: Trask's _Historical Linguistics_ has a whole section on this problem, with multiple examples of different types. He also deals with the extreme views like Proto-World, also with multiple examples.

Comment: Interesting to see that the people voting down and putting the question on hold have nothing else to contribute here. Before voting down or putting on hold at least show the decency to attribute at least one advice on correcting the question if you find it worthwhile to downvote. Unless you have personal reasons not to off course. To all others I ask to upvote and show that good questions about comparative etymology can be asked here and need to be answered too. Stop the poverty of the silent critics. They know who they are. 

Comment: My comment was supposed to be embodied in the reason for closure but sometimes it doesn't work out that way on the final tally. Unclear what you are asking. Can we delete everything but the last sentence, and would that then be your question? Is this distinct from the question "what is a significant generalization"? If this only about animal names, is this only about historical linguistics? How is this different from the two completely distinct questions "When does nonsense become a pattern" and "When does coincidence become a pattern"?

Comment: @user6726 I thought about it. The animals are just one category and are examples of that which I see as a comparative etymological pattern, which others see as either nonsense or coincidence. So the question should be clear that the animal category is an example either of coincidence or my brain thinking up nonsense or it is a valuable pattern that needs to be analysed to get grip on the methods to identify them and get a deeper understanding of words, roots, meanings and contexts in the dance of the tongue. Let’s skip to content instead of form and get good answers to this phenomenon.

Comment: So can we delete everything but the last sentence, and would that then be your question?

Comment: Why delete the introduction and the example? We can leave them there and Yes please answer the question in the end.

Comment: Because, currently, you're not asking the question at the end. You're asking a different question about animals and the derivation of their names from arbitrary phrases in different languages.

Comment: I am working on a comparative method to eventually proof there are logical patterns. What I would like to learn is, what makes linguists interpret data as coincidence and nonsense. Some examples may be nonsense, some may be cognates. That is beyond the point here. We have been there with other answers and questions. I will leave this question here, because I still would like to see evidence of disproof, not statements about what you think is arbitrary or nonsense or imagination. I am not interested in personal opinions about the comparative etymological methods.

Comment: Currently I am asking the question in the end. There is a question mark behind the sentence. Claiming it is not that question I am asking is arbitrary nonsense.

Comment: This Stack Exchange community is one of the most biased I have encountered. That really is a shame. People are more concerned with voting than the love for knowledge and progression. But if it works like that, a 100 reputation for the best answer to this question.

Comment: Historical linguistics has no explanation for the origin of words like wasp. But let’s see what nonsense comes forward. Who dares???

Comment: I just want an incentive for you all to start using your brains. I don’t believe you are stupid, just the historical linguistic methods so far are weak. But we can get to that later.

Answer (score 6):

As a general rule, coincidences and nonsense become a pattern when you can show a consistent rule that can explain a significant amount of data.

Historical linguistics offers many such patterns. One of the first noticed (which led to historical linguistics becoming a thing in the first place) was that `/p/` in Latin and Greek corresponds to `/f/` in Germanic: pisc- ~ fish, pod- ~ foot, pater ~ father, pyr ~ fire, and many more. This is now known as (one component of) Grimm's Law.

On the other hand, there's no regularity to the correspondences you've proposed. For otter~water, you're relying on rhyming in certain dialects of English—in RP, for example, they have different vowels. Sheep and shaven, on the other hand, have the same first phoneme and a labial somewhere after that, owl and *vole* have the same final sound in two different languages and vaguely-related meanings, and wasp corresponds rather tenuously to an entire phrase in a different language.

So the general standard is: if you can show a consistent pattern that can make predictions, rather than having to come up with separate explanations for each instance, then it'll be considered a pattern rather than a series of coincidences.

Comment: I don’t think it is one rule that can explain it, unless the rules are categorised as: To not be coincidence “The similarity in spelling must lead to an explanation that links the animal name to its features, use to humans, sound it makes besides geographical features like ‘mountain’ lion. There should be other options kept open. And in different languages the same rules should be applied if it is not a compounded foreign phrase as wasp which has the rule work in French, not English.

Comment: Now you can make predictions. I am sure this works for most if not all domestic animals in the Germannic countries.

Comment: Maybe simplify. Every name is a description existing of compounded roots or words.

Comment: Just for the record: "otter" and "water" really are cognates.

Comment: ...As are "fly" n. and "fly" v.